# What is a good architecture for a Lift-JPA application?

Tags: architecture, scala, jpa, lift

I was wondering what is the best practice for a JPA model in Lift? I
noticed that in the jpa demo application, there is just a Model object
that is like a super object that does everything. I don't think this
can be the most scalable approach, no?

Is it is wise to still do the DAO pattern in Lift? For example,
there's some code that looks a tad bloated and could be simplified
across all model objects:

```
Model.remove(Model.getReference(classOf[Author], someId))
```

Could be:

```
AuthorDao.remove(someId)
```

I'd appreciate any tips for setting up something that will work with
the way Lift wants to work and is also easy to organize and maintain. Preferably from someone who has actually used JPA on a medium to large Lift site rather than just postulating what Spring does (we know how to do that) ;)

The first phase of development will be around 30-40 tables, and will
eventually get to over 100... we need a scalable, neat approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposted from the Lift mailing list for posterity ([source here](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/msg/dbb89e8b020ffd22)):

I can shed a little light on how we use JPA. I'm not sure what kind of
container you are working with, but we are using JBoss 4.2.2, and
using its connection pool facilities.

We utilize the scalajpa library to initialize the JPA stuff and keep a
reference to the entity manager in a thread local variable. We
specifically don't use the Lift RequestVarEM, because the lifecycle of
a RequestVar is somewhat more complicated than a regular HTTP request,
and this can lead to connections not being returned to the pool in a
timely fashion.

The first step is to create the "model", and point it at the unit name
from your persistence.xml:

```
object MyDBModel extends LocalEMF("unitName", false) with
ThreadLocalEM
```

And we've created a little bit of code to make some operations simple.
Each of our persistent classes mixes in a that provides some basic JPA
operations:

```
trait Persistent {
   def persist = DBModel.persist(this)
   def merge = DBModel.merge(this)
   def remove = DBModel.remove(this)

}
```

For example,

```
@Entity
@Table{val name="person"}
class Person extends Persistent {

@Id
var id:String = _

@Column {val name="first_name", val nullable = false, val
updatable=false}
var firstName:String = _

@Column {val name="last_name", val nullable = false, val
updatable=false}
var lastName:String = _

@OneToMany{ ... }
var roles:Set[Role] = new HashSet[Role]()

// etc.

}
```

We primarily use the mapped collections to navigate the object model,
and put more complex database methods on the companion object, so that
we don't have references to MyDBModel scattered throughout the code
(as you noted, an undesirable practice). For example:

```
object Person {
def findByLastName = MyDBModel.createQuery[Person]
("...").findAll.toList

// etc.

}
```

Lastly, our integration with Lift is in the form of a bit of code that
wraps each request:

```
S.addAround(new LoanWrapper {
   def apply[T](f: => T):T = {
      try {
         f
      }
      catch {
         case e => MyDBModel.getTransaction.setRollbackOnly
      }
      finally {
         MyDBModel.cleanup
      }
   }

})
```

I've left out some error handling here to make the idea clearer, but
the intent is that each HTTP request executes in a transaction, which
either succeeds or fails in its entirety. Since MyDBModel is
initialized when it is first touched, in your test code you can rig up
the EM as you see fit, and the data objects are isolated from this
configuration.

Hope this is useful.

Sean

Comment: How do you test code that relies so heavily on global variables (like `MyDBModel` in your example). Isn't it complicated to do without involving the whole stack?